# How to check IAP Auto Renewable Subscription was already purchased by Apple ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I need to get auto-renew subscription working in this project. This project allows a user to sign up to our product after paying for a subscription. This works fine but if I decide to use the same Apple ID to register again, the app doesn't ask me to purchase the membership, instead it says "You're currently subscribed to this." and then pushes me through with a valid purchase.

I have been looking for some way around this problem, and this IS a problem seeing that people can get away with free accounts by registering for an account with his friends Apple ID, but I couldn't come across any possible solutions.

Has anyone had this problem before? How can I avoid this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

So you've encountered one of the difficult aspects of using Apple subscriptions.

To guarantee that people can't abuse their Apple IDs to get free content, you need to send the [App Store receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html) to your backend and parse out all of the `transaction_identifier`s and attach those to the original account. Then when the second user tries to post the same receipt you can check if the given `transaction_identifier`s are already providing content to someone else.

Unfortunately this non-trivial and requires a fair bit of code and understanding of the IAP system. If you want to get the benefits without doing the work you can use a service like [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) (disclaimer: This is my company). We do all that stuff in our backend, you just send us the receipt and we tell if a user is subscribed or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually have a backend process set up already using Firebase.
Once the transaction is successful, I push the receipt data through and get it validated. Once I do that I store the receipt with the expiration time for that user.
I never thought of using the identifier as well